When is it safe to drop redundant or duplicated indexes on AWS RDS MySQL?
To identify redundant and duplicate indexes while ignoring primary and foreign keys and checking their cardinality. What is the best practice for dropping indexes on AWS RDS MySQL databases in the AWS RDS environment?
My environment(context): AWS RDS Aurora MySQL 8.0
The purpose is to reduce storage costs and improve INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE transactions.

When you ask for best, it makes it a matter of opinion which is off-topic.  Best for what - space, speed, aesthetics, ram?

@Rohit Gupta 'Best' for reducing cost with storage and improving INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE transactions

TOPIC 1 : Duplicate indexes
Without using additional tools, you could use sys.schema_redundant_indexes
Here is what it looks like in MySQL 5.7.37:
MySQL (none)> desc sys.schema_redundant_indexes;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| table_schema               | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| table_name                 | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| redundant_index_name       | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| redundant_index_columns    | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| redundant_index_non_unique | bigint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dominant_index_name        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| dominant_index_columns     | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dominant_index_non_unique  | bigint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| subpart_exists             | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| sql_drop_index             | varchar(223) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL (none)>

The suggested indexes to drop are
SELECT sql_drop_index FROM sys.schema_redundant_indexes;

The other columns help explain to you why they can be dropped.
If you want a deeper dive into this, I highly recommend you use the tool pt-duplicate-key-checker. Why ? Here is what it will output

pt-duplicate-key-checker reads sys.schema_redundant_indexes and gives you a plain text description of why you can drop an index.
If pt-duplicate-key-checker sees an index whose PRIMARY columns are included in the duplicate index, it will suggest dropping the index and adding it back without the PRIMARY columns (see my answer to Run pt-online-schema-change with multiple ALTER queries synchronously from December 2022)
pt-duplicate-key-checker will also suggest the dropping of duplicate foreign keys (I have seen clients with duplicate foreign keys, so I am glad Percona added this feature)

For those using MySQL 8.0+
Before dropping any duplicate indexes, you should see if your queries can live without them. For example, if you have a table called mydb.mytable and you have an duplicate index called index99, you can hide the presence of that index from the query optimizer like this:
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ALTER INDEX index99 INVISIBLE;

Then, let your queries have at it. If the query performance is the same, then you can drop the index:
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable DROP INDEX index99;

Otherwise, keep the index:
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ALTER INDEX index99 VISIBLE;

NOTE : These principles apply to RDS, Aurora, local VMs, and bare metal.
Captain's Log : Supplemental
The difference between a duplicate index and a redundant index is this

A redundant index is an index who ordered columns are identical to a prefix of another index (i.e. index1 with columns (a,b) is a redundant index of index2 (a,b,c))
A duplicate index is an index who ordered columns are identical to another index (i.e. index1 with columns (a,b) is a duplicate index of index2 (a,b))

TOPIC 2: What about cardinality ???
You can just run
SHOW INDEXES FROM mydb.mytable\G

This will should you the cardinality of a single column, then grouped by 2 columns, 3 columns, etc.
Let's say you have an index on 3 columns (a,b,c) in mydb.mytable. You can get the cardinality of the three columns like this:
SELECT a,b,c,COUNT(1) cnt FROM mydb.mytable GROUP BY a,b,c;

This will give you an idea which 3-tuple would use an index and which would not. The cnt column for a 3-tuple is more than 5% of the table, the index would be ignored and you'd see a full index scan or a full table scan.

Nevertheless the user must analyse this "duplications" carefully. Sometimes the server suggestion is obviously wrong. Examples.

Thank you @RolandoMySQLDBA for the detailed explanation.
